# Does combining polygons reduce load?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm making an app similar to this: [image: Tracking app]

Basically every time the user moves it adds a new polygon from their previous location to their new location.  Hover ever I am experience performance problems quite early on.

Would grouping the polygons to decrease the number of polygons improve performance or is the problem just the number of points rendered?

Answer (score 0):

Are you drawing the polygons in the onDraw of your view? I found that drawing things on a bitmap outside of onDraw, then drawing the bitmap in onDraw sped up my code.

Comment: They are vectors like this: `mMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()` . Is there a way to display them as bitmaps instead?